# Is it OK to edit a question to remove unnecessary background details?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I recently edited a question to remove an introduction sentence that I thought unecessary to the problem solving:

> I currently have an online shop selling carpets and rugs.

Considering that the question was tagged "woocommerce" (implying that the question is about an online shop) and the fact that user is selling carpets have absolutely no relevance, I thought that this sentence should be considered as noise and needed to be removed.

Though my edit [was rejected by two reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9111105) before being accepted by the OP for the following reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

While I agree it's a minor improvement and anyway this is a low-quality question; I don't see how this edit could be of any harm, and in my opinion it's improving the readability of the question by removing noise and help readers to get straight to the question content.

So my question is, I am wrong about this? Is it OK to remove unnecessary background details like that or should I keep them in the future to preserve the "question spirit"?

Comment: Don't bother polishing turds.

Comment: @will: Especially old dry cat turds...

Comment: @Will I thought it was rugs not turds :) Joke apart, I guess you're right and that I shouldn't spend time on those kind of posts.

Comment: There's no instrinsic harm in the edit itself, but keep in mind that editing will push the question to the front of the "activity" feed. And since it's a useless question I would rather flag as "too broad" than push to the front page, a close flag would have been more suitable. So I would reject the edit on the basis that even though the edit was "good", the question remained useless.

Comment: Pushing it to the front means more close votes. Not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: I think this goes back to the whole thanks for looking and please help tag statements,  extra text has to be kept within reason but you will always have people argue with you about it.

Comment: There is something I don't get from the answer / comments below. Many of my edits come from the first post review queue, where "I'm done"  if "I've done one of the following:" [...] **Edit to improve the question's appearance or clarity** [...] Maybe I got this review task wrong or this sentence is unclear.

Comment: In some of those review queues there's a "Mark as unsalvagable" or "Mark as low quality" or even straight up a "Flag" option. If the question is unsalvagable, it should be flagged to close rather than editing. In the "First post" queue, there's the "Flag" option. Again, what @Will said.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Looks like a good edit to me. It made zero difference to the question that he owned a rug store.

We also do not need to know what he had for breakfast. This is a good use of editing that hopefully the OP will remember as he goes forward to cut the fluff and get to the point.

Comment: That's what I thought too. Thanks for the confirmation - as I'm starting with editing I wanted to be sure that those kinds of edits are going in the right way.

Comment: @vard Just remember to fix as much as you possibly can with an edit. It takes at least three reviewers (up to five) to spend a review vote (of which each reviewer only has twenty) to approve or reject your suggested edit. If I were to see a post with many issues, and that was the only thing that was fixed... I would reject and edit it myself, which would automatically reject your edit.

Comment: Agreed. People catch me on that kind of stuff about 1 out of 3 times that I post. I always appreciate it, and no, I don't always remember to cut the fluff. (If I'm in the middle of a persnickety problem, EVERYTHING seems relevant to me at the time. lol.) Sometimes it IS important that we're a travel company, for example. Other times, it is just noise.

Answer (score 14):

This was not a good use of the editing feature.

There's nothing wrong with the deletion itself. That's not the problem. Who cares about carpets and rugs? Removing such noise is generally encouraged. Keyword: *Generally*. But was it the sensible thing to do here?

You have to consider *all* the consequences of your action. Since you don't have [edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) yet, your edit had to be reviewed by others. So your edit got put in the edit review queue. Four people had to read your edit and make a call on whether it should be accepted or rejected. Given that it was a minor edit of an unsalvageable question (which ended up in the close queue anyway, appropriately so), this was a *total waste of their time* (and of yours).  People generally don't like to have their time wasted, and that may well be why two reviewers chose to reject your edit.

Once you hit 2k reputation, you'll get edit privileges; your edits won't have to be reviewed anymore. If at that point you still feel like making minor cosmetic tweaks to terrible questions, then, knock yourself out, I guess.

In the meantime, please be mindful of the reviewers' time and effort and consider it a limited resource. If you see a poor question, flag it as such, or let it be; don't make minor edits to it.

Comment: I read somewhere before on meta that the edit review queue get always flushed and that there is kind of more edit reviewers than edits - this is why I don't really bother with making only "major improvement edit". If I see that a question can be improve with a minor edit, I go for it - if reviewers can't get 20sec of their time to check it and rage-reject it instead that's not really my problem. Besides that, I didn't judged this question as unsalvageable - it was a poor quality question, yes, but not unsalvageable imho.

Comment: Closely related: [Requesting a "stop polishing turds" edit suggestion reject reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260302)

Comment: And considering the fact that the close queue seems to be much more of a problem (7.1k questions in close queue right now, and 0 in suggested edits), isn't a good thing to edit questions that should be closed to improve them -even just a bit- and, maybe, avoid them to go in the endless close queue?

Comment: @vard: If that wasn't a textbook example of an unsalvageable question by SO standards, then I don't know what is. Edits such as yours do not reduce the chance of such questions ending up in the close queue: even after the edit, the right thing to do is still to close it (and nuke it, as it promptly was). So it still ends up in the close queue (turd) but in addition to that, it has to go through the edit queue first (polishing), which is silly and pointless. Yes, there are a lot of edit reviewers. So let's throw them a turd to keep them busy? I disagree.

Comment: I didn't said that. I'm just saying that edit != flag, and that editing is harmless and in no world it's a disrespect on the reviewer. Perhaps I got the whole thing wrong here, but this is what I do when I read a new question: 1. read it through 2. edit if I see anything that can be removed/improved **without judging the question quality** - as GEOCHET pointed out even if the question need to be closed it would help the OP next time by let him know how to ask a good question - 3. downvote or upvote 4. flag it if necessary 5. comment / answer if I can.

Comment: In this case I went through all those steps except the flag part as I didn't had any flag left that day. IMHO the edit/downvote/flag are all part of a learning process for the OP and address different matters. And honestly this all "turd" thing is a but disgusting and sounds more like disrespect to me.

Comment: @vard: Never mind reviewer's time or the queue: if the question should be closed as it stands and your edit doesn't change that fact, then the time **you spent** editing could have been better used on polishing an open question that is going to stick around and be seen many times in the future.

Comment: And, again, wasting the reviewers' time/quota ...

Comment: @JoshCaswell I agree that those kinds of edits in the end could be seen as a lost of time (the question has been deleted now). Though I don't consider that I wasted my time, as the OP learned two different things from his question: 1. his question was bad and he should avoid such questions in the future. 2. he should try to cut the fluff and keep only necessary informations. I hope that his next question (if there is any) will be a good one now that he knows better what and how to ask.

Comment: @SamB About the reviewer time, if they can't take 20sec to read such small edits, I would just say : meh. They should do something else if their time is so valuable. And about their quota, I don't really see your point here: as I said there is more reviewers than edits to review. And anyway if they don't want to "waste" (weird way to see SO reviews tasks) their quota I'm sure they can skip the edit.

Comment: No. Just no. Hell no.

Comment: @GEOCHET: Just to clarify, whom are you saying no to?